# Kivy - UI Issues

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

Trying to create a simple Kivy GUI with two screens: a title screen and a control screen with a number of buttons. The main problem is navigating the GUI and letting the builder function properly. I just get a black screen at the moment on run.

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ContScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


backbone = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MasterApp(App):
    def build (self):
        return backbone


boApp = MasterApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    boApp.run()
```

**with the main .kv**

```
ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition

<IntroScreen>:
    name: "main"
    intro.kv

<ContScreen>:
    name: "cont"
    stacklayout.kv
```

**and the example screen (intro.kv)**

```
<IntroScreen>:
    FloatLayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 50

        Label:
            text: 'WELCOME'
            font_size: 50
            pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0}

        Image:
            source=('mylogo.png')
            pos_hint: {'x':0,'y':0}

        Button:
            text: 'Initialize'
            font_size: 35
            on_release: app.root.current = "cont"
```

Still learning Kivy so I know I'm doing something wrong. Would appreciate help figuring this out. EDIT: NAVIGATION SOLVED

**FOLLOW UP:**

```
<IntroScreen>:
    FloatLayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 50

        Label:
            text: 'WELCOME'
            font_size: 50
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}

        Image:
            source: 'mylogo.png'
            pos_hint: {'x':0,'y':0}

        Button:
            text: 'Initialize'
            font_size: 35
            on_release: root.manager.current = "cont"
```

Image not showing at all on the screen, just full button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution - Control Widget Size & Position

Use [size_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html) and [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint) to control the widget's size and position.

### intro.kv

```
<IntroScreen>:
    FloatLayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 50

        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: 'WELCOME'
            font_size: 50
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}

        Image:
            source: 'kivy-logo.png'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: 'Initialize'
            font_size: 35
            on_release: app.root.current = "cont"
```

### stacklayout.kv

```
<ContScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: 'Cont Screen'

        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: 'Main Screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'
```

### Output - size_hint & pos_hint

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

## Solution - Black Screen

### main.kv

- Use `include <file>` to add the kv files into main.kv

[Kivy Land Directives » incude <file>](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#lang-directives)

> ```
> include <file>
> ```
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> #:include [force] <file>
> ```
>
> Includes an external kivy file. This allows you to split complex
>   widgets into their own files. If the include is forced, the file will
>   first be unloaded and then reloaded again.

### intro.kv

- Replace `pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0}` with `pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}`
- Replace `source=('mylogo.png')` with `source: 'mylogo.png'`
- Replace `app.root.current` with `root.manager.current` because each screen has by default a property `manager` that gives you the instance of the [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage) used.

## Snippets

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:include intro.kv
#:include stacklayout.kv
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    IntroScreen:
        name: 'main'
    ContScreen:
        name: 'cont'
```

### intro.kv

```
<IntroScreen>:
    FloatLayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 50

        Label:
            text: 'WELCOME'
            font_size: 50
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}

        Image:
            source: 'mylogo.png'
            pos_hint: {'x':0,'y':0}

        Button:
            text: 'Initialize'
            font_size: 35
            on_release: root.manager.current = "cont"
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Very well done, everything flows correctly now. I do have a follow up question though. On the title screen I'd like the button to not take up the entire screen, and leave the top half with an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to updated post for controlling the widget's size and position.

Comment: Works great now. And since you provided such a thorough and concise answer, I'd like to refer you to another post of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444993/kivy-digital-clock-issues  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447113/controlling-arduino-gpio-through-serial-comms-from-raspberry-pi

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, feel free to up-vote and/or accept it, as you see fit. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)